# Why can't a create a new DIV in Magento?

Tags: javascript, html, magento

I am trying to create a new red div for each element in the loop on a Magento page. But nothing happens when I preview the page. My loop works and returns 3 alert boxes, so I expect to get 3 red divs with the code below but nothing happens!

```
var campaigns = document.getElementsByClassName("campaign");

for (var i=0, max= campaigns.length; i <= max; i++) {

//This alert works - alert("Campaign" + i);

var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

   newDiv.id = 'example'+i;
   newDiv.className = 'examples';
   newDiv.style.color = "red";
   document.appendChild(newDiv);

};
```

Comment: You're using base javascript to add the element. It should be there. Odds are it doesn't have anything in the div, so you don't see it. Try and add `newDiv.style.min-height = "20px";` to it.

Comment: I tried to set the height and added text to the Div, but I am still unable to see anything.

Comment: Can you post your existing html and complete js?

Answer (score 0):

In the for condition, you should use i < max, otherwise the loop will be executed one time more than it should.

Ir order for the div to be visible, you should set a text for it, or set the background-color, width and height.

Finally, you are appending the element to the document element, which does not actually make sense. You must replace by document.body.appendChild, or campaigns[i].appendChild.